# Debian 7 on Macbook

Tags: debian, macintosh

I have just installed Debian 7.1 on my Macbook Pro 9,2.  I'm trying to get the keyboard backlight to work properly.  I can press the F5/F6 keys to get an OSD to show up on the screen, but the backlight doesn't change.  The other buttons seem to work properly though, such as sound and backlight.  It looks like this is a GNOME setting, as I was messing around with the shortcuts and set a new shortcut to be the KbdBrightnessUp key, and of course that means that I don't get an OSD anymore.  I installed pommed, but that didn't do anything.

Questions:

1. Where is the shortcut for the keyboard backlight brightness?
2. Is there some setting that I need to change in order to get the keyboard backlight to work?

Answer (score 2):

Try echoing a value between 0 (off) and 255 (full brightness) to `/sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness`

Example: `echo 110 > /sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness`.

When I was putting various Linux's on my Macbook pro 3+ years ago, I think this was the only way I could get it to work. I wrote a script and bound the backlight keys to the script.